# Definition of "twisted group"

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$.

I encountered the following notion in an article:

"Let $\psi: \text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k) \to \text{Int}(\overline{G})$ be a cocycle. The **twisted group** $_\psi G$..."

How is this "twisted group" defined?

Comment: ... dare we presume there were more words of context?

Comment: Which article had this sentence?  What is $\operatorname{Int}(\overline{G})$?

Comment: presumably int(g bar) is the group of inner automorphisms of the base change of G to a separable closure of k (and psi is a 1-cocylce etc...)

Comment: Yes indeed, I thought this would be clear. The article is Borovoi's 1993 Duke paper, "Abelianization of the second nonabelian Galois cohomology".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the definitions in Serre's book "Galois cohomology". The relevant sections are I.5.3 - I.5.7. The idea is that if you have a group $G$ acting on a group $A$ and a cocycle $\psi\in H^1(G,A)$. The twisted group $_\psi A$ has the same group structure as $A$ but it has a twisted action by $G$, which is given by
$$g*a = \psi(g) \cdot (g \cdot a) \cdot \psi(g)^{-1}.$$
There is also a previous question which asked if there is an analog of this for outer automorphisms: [Substitute for Serre’s twisting when the “twisting” is outer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10048/substitute-for-serres-twisting-when-the-twisting-is-outer)